# C# asp.net - select image and save to database

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, image, border

What is the best way to perform this action on c# asp.net? 
**Scenario:** 
We have 4 images and the user need to mark the selected image (image gets border) - and by clicking `submit` button the selected image needs to be saved to the database.
We tried using JQuery, but on the submit process, but we couldn't get the selected image.
Thanks for advice.

the aspx page:

```
<div id="dragitem1">
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="selectImageDrag1" runat="server" />
                        <asp:Button ID="imageUploadDrag1" runat="server" Text="upload" OnClick="imageUploadDrag1_Click" />
                        <asp:Image ID="imageDrag1" runat="server" />
                        <div>

                   <asp:Image ID="image1DragArea1" runat="server" />
                        <asp:Image ID="image2DragArea1" runat="server"  />
                        <asp:Image ID="image3DragArea1" runat="server"  />
                        <asp:Image ID="image4DragArea1" runat="server"  />
                    </div>
```

the JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(function () {
for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
                $("#image" + i + "DragArea1").removeClass("showBorder");}
            $(this).addClass("showBorder");   
        });
    }
});
```

now... how the c# code behind should look like ?

Comment: The description makes it sound like these images are already on the page.  Are they being served from the application already?  Why would the images need to be saved to the database if they're already on the server?  Can't you just save the selection and not the image itself, creating a many-to-many relationship between images and users?

Comment: the user uploads the images - but they are saved to a folder and not to the Database (where there is no connection between user and image). by clicking on submit button the image is saved as a "user choice" at the database... we dont want to insert images with no users to the database...

Comment: So... by the time the user submits the form, the images are already saved server-side.  How do you uniquely identify each image when displaying them on the form?  You'd use that unique identifier when saving the user's selection to the database.  This is really nothing more than guessing and conjecture without any actual code sample, though.  You claim that you made an attempt but something about that attempt didn't work.  We can help identify the problem in that attempt if you actually show it to us.

Comment: i added the code so far...

Comment: `"now... how the c# code behind should look like ?"` - You're not actually telling the server-side code which element was selected.  (I don't even see how your client-side code is "selecting" an item either.)  Whatever event is triggered client-side when the user selects an item, that event should be setting a hidden field of some sort with the selected value so that the server-side can receive that value from the form.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect there is more behind the scenes to this question:

The images I would assume are rendered to the page dynamically, which means there will be a unique reference for each image, which may be part of the id or other attribute of the image. It will be a reference to this image that you would need to save rather than the image itself, since the image already exists somewhere.

Edit:

The reference could be the image name as these will be unique within the folder.

Comment: but how can i get the user choice? the selected image gets border - and thats represent the user choice. if i click on submit then on the code behind "the new class" is not accesseble...

Comment: @user2828251: That's because the client doesn't send CSS data to the server.  When the user selects an element in the client-side code, you should also set a value on a hidden form element to indicate the selection.  That form element will then be included in the request to the server, telling the server-side code what was selected.